# Does Android 7 require longer confirmation for the BLE disconnect?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, btle

I have noticed a weird BLE behaviour after updating some of my devices to Android 7. 
Basically it seems that Android 7 requires longer time to close the connection causing the BLE device, which was previously connected to Android, to fail when reconnecting. More specifically, Android is returning empty list for services discovered in the onServicesDiscovered() callback. It appears that after calling close() I need to have the BLE device powered ON for about 2 seconds in order to correctly disconnect it from Android device. In the previous versions of Android we could have shut down the BLE device almost immediately and it would reconnect to Android without any issues. Does anyone know what has changed in the Android 7 BLE stack to cause this? It seems wrong to keep the BLE device waiting extra time just to disconnect cleanly.
(I have tried this only on Samsung devices so it could be something related to Samsung possibly)

Comment: No there is no such change. To see what's going on, look at the hci snoop log or use an air sniffer.